# How to decrypt a 2 rail fence cypher. I have not learned the def command yet and every help online has given me a function (def)

Tags: python

Question: write a python program for the decryption of 2-rail fence cipher. For example, the user input "Cmhmtmrooeoeoorw" should return "Comehometomorrow", and input "topaesw lyr" should return "two players".

Comment: You don't necessarily need a function, but you do need a loop.  You'll need to know half the string's length (`len(s)//2`).  You loop through half the length, printing out character #i and character #(i+halflength).

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) -- we're happy to help with a specific technical problem you encountered while writing your own code, but we don't just do your homework for you; you need to get far enough on your own to encounter a unique, specific, narrow technical problem, and communicate that problem clearly.